# Mir wurde gesagt passiv für man hat mir gesagt

Tags: grammatical-case, passive, conjugation

Mir dämmern Bedenken : ist es korrekt zu sagen

```
"Mir wurde gesagt, dass"
```

wenn der, der sagt, nicht definiert ist, statt

```
"Man hat mir gesagt, dass"
```

Ist es korrekt und schön ausgedrückt ?

Comment: Beides korrekt und schön ausgedrückt. Auch *Mir dämmern Bedenken.* ist schön ausgedrückt! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Beides ist korrektes, gutes Deutsch und gebräuchlich. Es ist im Wesentlichen eine Frage des Geschmacks und der persönlichen Vorliebe welche der beiden Formulierungen man verwendet.